# Pierdo un registros en la consulta

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando traer los registros de mi db, que imprima una cantidad especifica de registros en la primera fila, y al llegar a este numero, pase a imprimir en la siguiente fila. Y asi sucesivamente hasta que se acaben los registros. Pero cada vez que repite el ciclo, pierdo un registro. He intentado todo, y ya no se que hacer.

Esto es lo que quisiera imprimir:

```
-------------------
|      Tabla      |
|-----------------|
|Reg1 |Reg2 |Reg3 |
|-----------------|
|Reg4 |Reg5 |Reg6 |
|-----------------|
|Reg7 |Reg8 |Reg9 |
|-----------------|
-------------------
```

Y esto es lo que me trae:

```
-------------------
|      Tabla      |
|-----------------|
|Reg1 |Reg2 |Reg3 |
|-----------------|
|Reg5 |Reg6 |Reg7 |
|-----------------|
|Reg9 |R10  |R 11 |
|-----------------|
-------------------
```

Adjunto mi codigo:

```
<div class = "card">
    <div class = "card-header"></div>
    <div class = "card-body">
        <table id = "example1" class = "table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr><th style = "text-align: center">CI</th></tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php  
                    $query =    mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM jobd") or die('error: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
                    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                    {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div class = "row d-flex align-items-stretch">
                    <?php  
                        $num = 1;
                        do
                        {
                    ?>
                    Digital Strategist <?php echo $num ?>
                    <h2 class = "lead"><b><?php echo $data['codigo'] ?></b></h2>
                    <h2 class = "lead"><b><?php echo $data['cargo'] ?></b></h2>
                    <?php  
                    $num++;
                    }
                    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) AND ($num < 4))
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <?php
                            }      
                    ?>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar el `while` asi: `while ($num < 4 AND $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))`

Comment: Pierdes los datos por esta condición `($num < 4)` por eso no tienes el registro 4 y 8. Si tienes más registros todos los múltiplos de 4 no aparecerán.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la respuesta @alanfcm Era justo el error que tenia.

Answer (score 1):

EL problema está en cómo operas sobre el resultado de la consulta.

CUando haces

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
?>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
    <div class = "row d-flex align-items-stretch">
<?php  
            $num = 1;
            do
            {
?>
Digital Strategist <?php echo $num ?>
<h2 class = "lead"><b><?php echo $data['codigo'] ?></b></h2>
<h2 class = "lead"><b><?php echo $data['cargo'] ?></b></h2>

<?php  
                $num++;
            }
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) AND ($num < 4))
?>
```

La primera vez que haces `$data = mysqli_fetch...` traes la siguiente fila del resultado, luego en el do-while vuelves y traes la siguiente fila a partir de la segunda iteración del do-while y validas si $num es menor que 4. Necesariamente va a haber casos en los que la condición no se cumple e igual te moviste en la lista de resultados y esos son los registros que pierdes, cuando haces el fetch pero el resultado es false

La sugerencia es que hagas sólo el primer while, en el que recorres TODOS los elementos de la respuesta y ya dentro de este while uses SÓLO validaciones sobre $num para decidir si pintas un td, un tr o lo que desees pintar en el documento.